object data push using map function in react/javscript
object array
{ 
 first : { label :"a" , status : true , text: "dummy" },
 second : { label :"b" , status : true , text: "dummy" },
 third : { label :"c" , status : false , text: "dummy" }
 }

I have the object and map and push inot other object check the object key have label is "c" ,if present then dont push
 const newData = data && data.map(item => {
            if(item.label !=='c') {   
                return {
                ...item, 
                };
            }
            }); 

expected result
{ 
 first : { label :"a" , status : true , text: "dummy" },
 second : { label :"b" , status : true , text: "dummy" } 
 }


The map always returns new array of the same length. you can either get your result with the filter or reduce.
const newData = data && data.filter(item => item.label !== 'c');

OR
    const newData = data && data.reduce((acc, item) => {
     if (item.label !== 'c') {
      acc[item.label] = item;
     }
     return ACC;
    }, {});


You are also used this method:
const data = {
  first: { label: "a", status: true, text: "dummy" },
  second: { label: "b", status: true, text: "dummy" },
  third: { label: "c", status: false, text: "dummy" }
};

const filteredData = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(data).filter(([key, value]) => value.label !== 'c')
);


this is tried and working fine using object entries
 let newData ={}; 
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) { 
      if(value.label !=='c') {
        newData[key] =value;
      }
    }
console.log("ne",newData);

